# Word or phrase that can mean something and its opposite

Tags: terminology

Is there such a thing in the English language as words or phrases that can mean a something or its opposite depending on the **context** in which they are employed, *without* the use of sarcasm?

If so, how are they named?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) has a pretty long list of names for words like this:

> An **auto-antonym** (sometimes spelled **autantonym**), or **contronym** (also spelled **contranym**), is a word with a homograph (another word of the same spelling) which is also an antonym (a word with the opposite meaning). An auto-antonym is alternatively called an **antagonym**, **Janus word** (after the Roman god), **enantiodrome**, **self-antonym**, **antilogy**, or **addad** (Arabic, singular **didd**). It is a word with multiple meanings, one of which is defined as the reverse of one of its other meanings. This phenomenon is called **enantiosemy**, **enantionymy**, or **antilogy**.

**EDIT:** If anyone's interested, [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwfzlBYqtd4%20here's) a brief video that explains the etymologies of some common auto-antonyms (the video uses the term "contronyms").

Comment: "Janus word" is a pretty good one indeed.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Hmph. Well, at least this one’s better than _Janus-faced_, I suppose …

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring perhaps to [auto-antonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym)? (Also known by other names,  such as *contranyms*.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite good term: [*"chameleon words"*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=a-3WAAAAMAAJ&q=%22chameleon+words%22&dq=%22chameleon+words%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V3QRVYqsEdSpyASciIKQBQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBg)

> The Way of Words: An Informal Logic - Page 71
>
> Ronald Munson - 1976
>
> But **chameleon words** have no identity separate from their disguises. They are what they are made to be by the users of the words.