# Term for words which can have the same or opposite meanings in same contexts

Tags: terminology, antonyms

In [Term for words which can have the same or opposite meanings in different contexts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334695/term-for-words-which-can-have-the-same-or-opposite-meanings-in-different-context),

> hot and cool are opposite temperatures, but can also both be used to mean fashionably attractive/impressive.

I would like to know if there is a reference for words that can signify opposing meanings in the same context. Examples:

- Shaft

  - A rod or cylinder-shaped solid object (of a tool or weapon)
  - A rod or cylinder-shaped hole (of a mine, elevator, tool, or weapon)
- Non-plussed

  - So surprised and confused that one is unsure how to react
  - Not disconcerted; unperturbed

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235283/word-or-phrase-that-can-mean-something-and-its-opposite) links to the [Wikipedia page Contronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contronym) which has a short list. If you google for lists of contronyms you'll get more (technically, requests for resources are supposed to go on Meta, but this is probably covered already in other questions).

Comment: *nonplussed* is not a contronym, unless you accept erroneous usage.